# Error with the open() function in python

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

Every time I try to run this program I got from this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rioXu6EBN0s (minute 16), I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6T1fi.jpg) error:

> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes
>   in position 0-1: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape.

This is the code that I wrote:

```
my_variable = "<html><head><title>My HTML File</title></head><body><h1>Hello world!</h1></body></html>"

my_html_file = open("\Users\hp\Desktop\Code\Python testing\CH\my_html_file.html", "w")

my_html_file.write(my_variable)
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting the error and how I can fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\U` at the beginning of the string tells Python that you are trying to enter a numeric Unicode character. You don't follow it up with a number, so you get an error.

Stick an `r` in front of the string literal to prevent `\` from being interpreted specially:

```
open(r"....")
```

In the future, please put the code and the error message in the question.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will keep that in mind for future posts. Is this ``r`` trick only for this example or can I use it for other misinterpretations? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, you can use it in many places. It's very convenient when you have a lot of backslashes in a string, like a Windows file path or a regular expression. (Although, for future reference, Windows also accepts forward slashes, so you could just use those instead.)

Comment: Without the code and error message, how is anyone supposed to find this question and answer in the future?

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I'll edit the post.